# Инициализация динамического массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Как проиницилизировать динамический массив целых чисел (`int`) при его объявлении?

Comment: А как вы его создаете?

Comment: int *A=new int [n]

Comment: @cool_guy Используйте правки вопроса для внесения в него важной информации.

Comment: Похоже что никак...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов че так?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а как еще тогда можно его создать?

Comment: Вообще странно что вам надо динамический массив, для которого вы знаете число и значения элементов.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов так я потом буду увеличивать их число

Comment: Вам придется использовать копирование одного в другой, так можете смело создавать обычный массив и копировать его в новосозданный динамический.

Comment: чето затратно, а через скобки ()

Comment: `int *A=new int [n]; memcpy(A, your_static_array, sizeof(your_static_array));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте `vector<int>`. У него есть конструктор:

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

Вот в него передайте число элементов и начальное значение.

Или можете передать начальные значения в этот конструктор, если они у вас уже есть:

```
template <class InputIterator>
         vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

Использование вектора решит все ваши проблемы с изменением размера динамического массива в последующем.

---

Если вам нужен голый массив, то можно забить его нулями, записав в конце скобочки:

```
new int[n]();
```

А конкретные значения поддерживаются современными компиляторами:

```
new int[n] { 1, 2 };
```

Comment: емае я не про вектор спрашивал а про динамический массив

Comment: на готовеньком любой могет

Comment: @cool_guy И зачем вам "динамический массив", если вы собираетесь потом изменять его размер? Вы пользуетесь не тем инструментом. Ну и вектор — это и есть "динамический массив", в отличие от того массива, который вы создаёте через new[].

Comment: ну задание такое что поделать, конечно проще вектор юзать

Comment: можно с динамическми какнить?

Comment: @cool_guy Обновил.

Comment: сяп))))))))))))))))

Comment: интересно на англоязычном сайте так же заваливают спецом?

Comment: @Athari вопросы "зачем" следует задавать ПОСЛЕ ответа по существу, а не до него, ОК????